# List of files in /tmp Linux - Java

Tags: java, linux, spring, maven

How to get the list of files in /tmp folder in Linux?

I tried with,

```
        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp.txt", ".tmp");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        File[] tmpFiles = temp.listFiles();
```

But this doesn't work?

Basically I want to delete some files in /tmp directory of linux.

Comment: You need to create a pointer to /tmp and then check it exists and finally iterate through the folder contents

Comment: You might want to read this doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-